# I want to make overflow-x hidden and overflow-y visible

Tags: html, css, reactjs, slider, overflow

I have been stuck on this problem for so many days. What I have been trying to achieve is like this,

I have a slider div set it's width and height in which I have boxes sitting next to each other as children. So I want the horizontal overflow of the slider to be hidden(boxes that go outside of the width of the slider). Which can easily be achieved with overflow-x hidden. But the problem is when I hover a box I want to expand it's width and height and show more content and I want them to overflow the slider vertically. Because of that overflow hidden that doesn't work. They got hidden as well. And I want to expand that box's width and height without pushing it's siblings. Example is just like Netflix displays it's movies. When you hover a movie it got expanded and more content is shown.

This is what I have been able to achieve so far

```
.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  height: 8rem;
  border: 3px solid green;
  margin: 4rem auto;
}
.slider {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.boxes {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box-container {
  position: relative;
}
.box {
  width: 8rem;
  height: 8rem;
  background: purple;
  margin-right: 3px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
.box:hover {
  height: 20rem;
  width: 15rem;
}




<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="slider">
        <div class="boxes">
          <div class="box-container">
            <div class="box"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is what I want to accomplish  https://demo.vodlix.com/

Answer (score 3):

```
overflow-y: visible;
overflow-x: clip;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla </div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want to do this then you have to use these:

```
overflow-x:hidden;
overfloy-y:scroll;
```

Comment: That's not really what I want to do. I want overflow on y axis to be visible without push the content around it. Scrolling is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

### This complete slider without bootsatrap

You may need something like this

it's work without ***bootstrap.***

Try this if work , dring some cofee ! ;D

***CSS***

```
.flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;

    -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.row { 
    -webkit-flex-direction: row; 
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-item {
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    padding: 5px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: contain;
    display: table;

    line-height: 50px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}

.mamOfmom{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Use ***class="mamOfmom"*** for the main of element in it I made ***overflow-x: scroll*** so that it scrolls ***sideways.***

And ***class="flex-container row"*** to make the ***child flex sideways.***

And use ***class="flex-item"*** for ***child/Image.***

***HTML***

```
<div class="mamOfmom">
    <div class="flex-container row">
            <img class="flex-item" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300">

            <img class="flex-item" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300">
        
            <img class="flex-item" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale">
        
            <img class="flex-item" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300">
    
            <img class="flex-item" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300">
    
            <img class="flex-item" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale">

            <img class="flex-item" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300">

            <img class="flex-item" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300">
        
            <img class="flex-item" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale">
        
            <img class="flex-item" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300">
    
            <img class="flex-item" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300">
    
            <img class="flex-item" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale">

    </div>
</div>

<h3>If Me not move its work</h3>
```